# An elegant way to upsert into list

Tags: language-agnostic

So, I have a list of objects, and I want to update items matching some criteria and insert an object if nothing matches. The code I've came up with doesn't look elegant, it goes something like this:

```
def upsert(type, text)
  messages.each do |message|
    if message.type == type
      message.text = text
    end
  end

  unless messages.any?{|message| message.type == type}
    messages.insert(Message.new(type, text))
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the implementation of the list itself. If you can implement your list with a unique hash for each of the element, fetching an element may be pretty trivial.

So it boils down to the implementation of the list itself. If it is some kind of a random access list (fetches constant over time), this operation would be simple. If the list is a pure sequential access list, this optiation would be the same as your implementation.

For instance in with a Java [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) I would do this:

Assuming 'type' uniquely identifies an element, I would have a [correctly](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05273/index.html) defined [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [`hashcode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) in the Item class.

```
if(list.contains(item))
{
    Item item = list.get(list.indexOf(item));
    item.setText(text);
}
else
{
    list.add(item);
}
```

If `type` is not unique, the implementation is still possible. The bottomline is the implementation of the list. With a good random access list, things are almost always simple:

```
if(!list.contains(item))
{
    return;
}
do
{
    int i = list.indexOf(item);
    Item item = list.get(i);
    item.setText(text);
    list = list.subList(i+1, list.size());
} while(list.indexOf(item) != list.lastIndexOf(item));
```

Comment: No, type doesn't uniquely identifies an element, so multiple items could be updated

Comment: In that case, you need a more elegant approach. You still can use hashes and a random access list. Bottomline remains the same: depends on type of list. See my updated answer.